# Dynamic XML Template in .NET C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to make a request to a web service that uses SOAP in C#. I'm able to do this fine, but I'm looking for a more diligent way to do this.

I want to load XML from a file (template) and dynamically allocate values to `variables` .

My C#:

```
FollowUpResponse followUpResult = new FollowUpResponse
            {
                Completed = false,
                PaymentAccepted = false,
                Message = string.Empty
            };
            Guid payId = Guid.Parse(payRequestId);
            XmlDocument soapDoc = new XmlDocument();
            Account account = new Account
            {
                PayGateId = BigInteger.Parse(_tools.GetPaygateId()),
                Password = _tools.GetPaygatePassword()
            };
            soapDoc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?> " +
                            "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST\">" +
                            "<SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
                            "<ns1:SingleFollowUpRequest>" +
                            "<ns1:QueryRequest>" +
                            "<ns1:Account>" +
                            $"<ns1:PayGateId>{account.PayGateId}</ns1:PayGateId>" +
                            $"<ns1:Password>{account.Password}</ns1:Password> " +
                            "</ns1:Account>" +
                            $"<ns1:PayRequestId>{payId}</ns1:PayRequestId>" +
                            "</ns1:QueryRequest>" +
                            "</ns1:SingleFollowUpRequest>" +
                            "</SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
                            "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = _tools.CreateWebRequest();
            Stream stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            soapDoc.Save(stream);
```

Instead of the above, I want to have the below template, and assigned values to those variables.

Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:SingleFollowUpRequest>
            <ns1:QueryRequest>
                <ns1:Account>
                    <ns1:PayGateId> {{PayGateId}} </ns1:PayGateId>
                    <ns1:Password> {{Password}} </ns1:Password>
                </ns1:Account>
                <ns1:PayRequestId> {{PayRequestId}} </ns1:PayRequestId>
            </ns1:QueryRequest>
        </ns1:SingleFollowUpRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: This might be better asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since you don't have a problem that needs to be solved, but rather, you're looking to improve your code.

Comment: @devlincarnate when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the post above might be considered as _missing review context_ and thus closed as off-topic, which happens all too often...

Comment: I usually use Xml Linq and parse the generic portion of xml from a string.  The add the unique elements to the XDocument using Xml Linq methods.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can plug most json/xml objects into online convert tools to generate some C# for you. And then you can use plain c# classes instead of string manipulation like you're doing now. E.g:.

```cs
   /* 
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    */
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Account", Namespace="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST")]
    public class Account {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="PayGateId", Namespace="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST")]
        public string PayGateId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Password", Namespace="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="QueryRequest", Namespace="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST")]
    public class QueryRequest {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Account", Namespace="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST")]
        public Account Account { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="PayRequestId", Namespace="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST")]
        public string PayRequestId { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="SingleFollowUpRequest", Namespace="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST")]
    public class SingleFollowUpRequest {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="QueryRequest", Namespace="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST")]
        public QueryRequest QueryRequest { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope")]
    public class Body {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="SingleFollowUpRequest", Namespace="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST")]
        public SingleFollowUpRequest SingleFollowUpRequest { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Envelope", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope")]
    public class Envelope {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="SOAP-ENV", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string SOAPENV { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="ns1", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Ns1 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

I just picked a random site. For json i usually pick quicktype but that does not support xml only json.

Comment: Hold up. Visual Studio has this feature built in. You simply click Edit-> Paste Special -> XML to Classes. There's also a JSON version.

Comment: There's also a VS Code extension called quicktype which does that.

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi wow, i did not know and i'm glad i learned something new today :). Op however likes string manipulation more i gues.

Comment: Hey, I only learned about that two weeks ago XD

Answer (score 0):

I've settled on the solution below, if anyone is looking for something similar.

Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ ">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:SingleFollowUpRequest>
            <ns1:QueryRequest>
                <ns1:Account>
                    <ns1:PayGateId>{PayGateId}</ns1:PayGateId>
                    <ns1:Password>{Password}</ns1:Password>
                </ns1:Account>
                <ns1:PayRequestId>{PayRequestId}</ns1:PayRequestId>
            </ns1:QueryRequest>
        </ns1:SingleFollowUpRequest>

    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Code:

```
string xmlBody = String.Empty;
using (var reader =
    new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Templates/Payments/SingleFollowUpRequest.xml"))
{
    xmlBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
xmlBody = xmlBody.Replace("{PayGateId}", account.PayGateId.ToString());
xmlBody = xmlBody.Replace("{Password}", account.Password);
xmlBody = xmlBody.Replace("{PayRequestId}", payRequestId);
soapDoc.LoadXml(xmlBody);
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = _tools.CreateWebRequest();
Stream stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
soapDoc.Save(stream);
```